# two node.js call back function inside an intent

Tags: node.js, callback, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

In the following code ,the control is not reaching the second call back function 
it will execute until the console.log(params).

After directly it will go to response.tellwithcard().
since i am fetching  near by places(park) from current location using `Google map API` and pass the address of the place as a parameter to the another function to get a distance from current location to the address which i got from first function.but i am not able to reach to the distance function with the correct parameters.

May i know the reason behind the execution of only one method(function) in the below code.

```
 ActivityIntent: function(intent, session, response) {
     var location = '12.991791,77.727809';
     var vicinity = "";
     map.PlaceDetails(location, function(error, placeDetails) {
         if (!error) {
             var array = placeDetails.results[0];
             var vicinity = array.vicinity
             console.log("the vicinity is   " + vicinity);
             var name = array.name;


             var params = {
                 origins: location,
                 destinations: vicinity,
                 mode: 'walking',
                 units: 'imperial',
             };
             console.log(params);
             gmAPI.distance(params, function(error, result) {
                 console.log('error: ' + error);
                 console.log(' distance result is:' + result);
                 console.log("is result ok:" + result.status);
                 var array = result.rows[0].elements;
                 if (array[0].distance == undefined || array[0].duration == undefined) {
                     self.emit("unhandled");
                 } else {
                     console.log(array[0].distance.text);
                     console.log(array[0].duration.text);
                     var appendStr = "the distance from " + params.origins + "to" + params.destinations + "is" + array[0].distance.text + "and take" + array[0].duration.text;
                 }

                 response.tellWithCard(appendStr, "Fitband", appendStr);

             });

         } else {
             appendStr = " There are no places  for this  request ";
         }

         response.tellWithCard(appendStr, "MyProject", appendStr);
     });
 },
```

Here map.PlaceDetails is executing but  gmAPI.distance not.
and the out put in the amazon lambda skill (/console.aws.amazon.com) is below in which it will show result until  console.log(params);

```
START RequestId: c648c247-87ef-11e7-9701-7558b925f9ce Version: $LATEST
2017-08-23T10:42:35.685Z    c648c247-czxc87ef-11e7-9701-7558b925f9ce    session applicationId: amzn1.ask.skill.18364a7a-xcc7069-4a73-b958-ad7b475e53eb
2017-08-23T10:42:35.686Z    c648c247-87zczcef-11e7-9701-7558b925f9ce    dispatch intent = ActivityIntent
2017-08-23T10:42:36.368Z    c648c247-8xczxc7ef-11e7-9701-7558b925f9ce   the body is    [object Object]
2017-08-23T10:42:36.424Z    c648c247-87ef-11e7-9701-7558b925f9ce    the vicinity is   International Tech Park, ITPL Main Road, Bengaluru
2017-08-23T10:42:36.424Z    c648c247xxczzxc-87ef-11e7-9701-7558b925f9ce { origins: '12.991791,77.727809',
  destinations: 'International Tech Park,Main Road, Bengaluru',
  mode: 'walking',
  units: 'imperial' }
END RequestId: c648c247-87ef-11ezxczc7-9701-7558b925f9ce
REPORT RequestId: c648c247-87ef-1zzcz1e7-9701-7558b925f9ce  Duration: 805.55 ms Billed Duration: 900 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 35 MB
```

Comment: Are you including properly the `gmApi`  module ?

Comment: yes.if i comment the first function and hard code the 'destination' variable to some address then the gmAPI will work .but when i integrate both it will not

Comment: how can i do the same using 'Promise'?